# build tool that can minify class names on web source files?

Tags: optimization, build, gruntjs, gulp, minify

Hi I'm following BEM method for naming the class names for a project, as the names are much descriptive and longer, I find it much verbose.

so each class names in the pattern, `block__element--modifier` is referenced on the `sass stylesheets`, `coffeescript` and the main `html` document, It would be better to rename it to `a` or `b` or some simple random class names .

Do there exists some tool that can be integrated to the build pipeline `gulp` or `grunt`, where the built code has minified html variables along the different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to compile your SASS into CSS and then use https://github.com/calebthebrewer/gulp-selectors to further reduce the verbose class names in the compiled CSS files.

It's possible that this library works directly with uncompiled SASS but I haven't tried it nor does it say so in the documentation.